# Can't get rid of the original x-axis tick labels

Tags: r, plot, histogram

So when I make a histogram the x axis tick labels default to a scientific notation (which I don't want) so I want to change them to the quartiles of the data.  When I run the following code, the new labels are added but the old are still there underneath.  It is unreadable.  How do I remove the original labels and replace them?

```
marks = c(171959, 429897, 509702, 581455, 862469)  
hist(net.worth$`Net Worth`, main="Net Worth", xlab="Net Worth", ylab="Customers", col="light blue")  
axis(1, at=marks, labels=marks)
```

Comment: options(scipen = 10)  
solved my original issue, but I still want to know what is causing this overlapping for the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get duplicated x-axis labels because you plot them two times: 1st time they are plotted together with the histogram using the `hist()` function. 2nd time they are added with the call to `axis()`.

You can suppress the drawing of original x-axis labels within `hist` by adding a `xaxt='n'` parameter:

```
marks = c(171959, 429897, 509702, 581455, 862469)  
hist(net.worth$`Net Worth`, main="Net Worth", xlab="Net Worth", xaxt='n', ylab="Customers", col="light blue")  
axis(1, at=marks, labels=marks)
```